# select minimum from two tables using left join

Tags: sql, oracle, greatest-n-per-group

I need to select the minimum of a set of dates across two tables and my SQL is so rusty that I can't think ...

I have a table with some business objects:

```
create table FOO (
  FOO_ID number(19, 0) not null,
  BAR varchar2(255),
  primary key (FOO_ID)
);
```

There are zero-or-many dates for this business object:

```
create table A_DATES (
  FOO_ID number(19, 0) not null,
  A_DATE date not null,
  primary key (FOO_ID , A_DATE)
);
```

And there is another set of zero-or-many dates for the same business object:

```
create table B_DATES (
  FOO_ID number(19, 0) not null,
  B_DATE date not null,
  primary key (FOO_ID , B_DATE)
);
```

The FOO table contains:

```
+------+--------+
|FOO_ID|A_STRING|
+------+--------+
|1     |aaa     |
|2     |bbb     |
|3     |ccc     |
+------+--------+
```

The A_DATES table contains:

```
+------+-----------+
|FOO_ID|A_DATE     |
+------+-----------+
|1     |01-Jan-2001|
|1     |01-Jan-2002|
|2     |01-Jan-2003|
|2     |01-Jan-2004|
+------+-----------+
```

The B_DATES table contains:

```
+------+-----------+
|FOO_ID|B_DATE     |
+------+-----------+
|1     |01-Jan-2003|
|1     |01-Jan-2004|
|2     |01-Jan-2001|
|2     |01-Jan-2002|
+------+-----------+
```

I have to write one select (*so no temporary tables etc*) that selects the minimum of either sets of dates, if any, for each FOO. The result set should look like this:

```
+------+--------+-----------+
|FOO_ID|A_STRING|MY_DATE    |
+------+--------+-----------+
|1     |aaa     |01-Jan-2001|
|2     |bbb     |01-Jan-2001|
|3     |ccc     |<null>     |
+------+--------+-----------+
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
select f.FOO_ID, f.A_STRING, min(d.dt) as 'MY_DATE'
from FOO f
left join (
  select FOO_ID, min(A_DATE) as dt from A_DATES group by FOO_ID
  union select FOO_ID, min(B_DATE) as dt from B_DATES group by FOO_ID
) d
  on f.FOO_ID = d.FOO_ID
group by
  f.FOO_ID, f.A_STRING
```

Comment: I needed to add a group-by to each half of the union, but otherwise, a good answer and quick

Comment: Sorry about that - added it in to the solution for completeness